# Android Emulator doesnt start under hyper-V VM

Tags: visual-studio, android-emulator, hyper-v, nova-hypervisor-show

The emulator just wait with back screen and nothing happen after that . I installed the latest version from everything , uninstalled and installed and no luck , this is the last part of output look and after that nothing show, there is also no error in all the output log

```
1>Waiting for runtime checks to completeStarting runtime checks

emulator: Starting QEMU main loop
emulator: registered 'boot-properties' qemud service
emulator: Adding boot property: 'ro.opengles.version' = '131072'
emulator: Adding boot property: 'qemu.sf.fake_camera' = 'both'
emulator: Adding boot property: 'dalvik.vm.heapsize' = '256m'
emulator: Adding boot property: 'qemu.hw.mainkeys' = '1'
emulator: Adding boot property: 'qemu.sf.lcd_density' = '480'
HAX is working and emulator runs in fast virt mode.
emulator: goldfish_events.have-dpad: false
emulator: goldfish_events.have-trackball: true
emulator: goldfish_events.have-camera: true
emulator: goldfish_events.have-keyboard: true
emulator: goldfish_events.have-lidswitch: false
emulator: goldfish_events.have-tabletmode: false
emulator: goldfish_events.have-touch: false
emulator: goldfish_events.have-multitouch: true
emulator: Adding boot property: 'monodroid.avdname' = 'Android_Accelerated_x86_Oreo'
emulator: control console listening on port 5554, ADB on port 5555
Not using any http proxy
emulator: Adding boot property: 'qemu.timezone' = 'America/New_York'
emulator: android_hw_fingerprint_init: fingerprint qemud listen service initialized
emulator: 'magic' skin format detected: 768x1280
emulator: 'magic' skin format detected: 768x1280
emulator: 'magic' skin format detected: 768x1280
emulator: 'magic' skin format detected: 768x1280
emulator: 'magic' skin format detected: 768x1280
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

found the issue 
you need to enable nested hyper-v on host machine